# get page contents curl error 404 in recieved html

Tags: php, html, curl, web-scraping, http-status-code-404

I am trying to get the page contents from an url.
This is the url i am trying to get the content of:

> https://www.facebook.com/events/383049449109054/

At the moment i am doing it the following way:

```
function GetHtmlContents( $url )
{
    $user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36';

    $options = array(

        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  =>"GET",        //set request type post or get
        CURLOPT_POST           => false,        //set to GET
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => $user_agent, //set user agent
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE     =>"cookie.txt", //set cookie file
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR      =>"cookie.txt", //set cookie jar
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
    );

    $ch      = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    $header['errno']   = $err;
    $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
    $header['content'] = $content;
    return $header;
}
```

this works great for the most part but in the recieved html there is an 404 error for some content i need:

> Network request encountered error HTTP 404 HTTP_CLIENT_ERROR:   404 Not Found
>
> ## Not Found
>
> The requested URL /api/graphql/ was not found on this server.

See images below the clarify the problem:

original page when visiting it from a browser as a normal user:
[image]
page when requesting it from curl in php:
[image]

How do i make sure this content is also returned by the curl request?
If more information is needed let me know so i can clarify!

Comment: I am not sure what i mean exactly, but in this case the first url is the correct url pointing to the page, but on this page there is a piece of html that gives the 404 error. the rest of the html on the curled url is shown. Hope this makes sense :)

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand. You should consider adding a screenshot.

Comment: just did, sorry for the size difference having some problems with changing the size

Comment: No problem. I now understand your issue.

Comment: Awesome, let me know if i can be of anymore assistance!

Comment: The root of the issue is that those nodes (Details, Featuring, Photos of Hosts, Photos at Luxor Live, and More Events at Luxor Live) are all loaded via AJAX so when you `echo $header['content'];` from your testing page you are trying to access http://localhost/api/graphql/ which does not exist on your server.

Comment: [See this image for clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DukC4.png)

Comment: great thanks for the information! is there a way how to solve this problem? or should i write a custom ajax request to get this data?